# Edit unknown binary file

Tags: file-format, binary

I have here an unknown binary file which contains a graphical user interface.
The file has the ending .kzb and it comes from the Kanzi desinger.
Unfortunately the Kanzi desinger can no longer edit the extracted binary file. Apparently you can only change something if you have the original project.
The file contains pictures that I would like to change. 
I know that it has to work, because someone has already done it, but doesn't want to reveal the secret :)
Here is the file I want to customize.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Z-RCdVGJv_jkKHcL3o_saOZz8sluMMG1?usp=sharing
In the file is a Chinese and an English flag (as .png) which I would like to change / swap.

Comment: If the task is find png files in your binary, with don't you make a script that do that? I dont think is hard to do it, find the png header in the file and then reconstruct the image and you will be able to modify it.

Comment: @camp0 If I knew how to do this, I wouldn‘t be here :)

Comment: @Alonia For extracting assets/resources there are several tools to do just that, like Dragon Unpacker. Check out http://wiki.xentax.com/index.php/Extraction_tools

Comment: @0xec Dragon Unpacker works fine, how can I exchange the edited file?

Comment: @Alonia You can use a [hex editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). Do a byte search for the start of the original PNG in the kzb file. Then you can overwrite the succeeding bytes with the modified PNG. However before that you need to ensure that both the original and modified PNG's are of the same size or you would overwrite other data.

Comment: @0xec Thanks, you really helped me.

Comment: @Alonia How did you go with this? I am working on basically exactly the same problem as you and would like to collaborate. Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: @rolls Is it also a .kzb file?

Comment: @Alonia yes it is. It looks like a fairly simple binary structure to modify. I haven't had  time to look at it again but feel free to contact me if you'd like to collaborate. I am trying to do something very similar (changing logo on a vehicles dash). I'd also consider going halves on getting someone on upwork to do it for us as I'm quite time poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Search the unknown binary file for the PNG magic number `89 50 4E 47 .PNG`
2. Determine size of the embedded PNG
3. Search unknown binary file for that size as a binary integer.
4. Replace PNG and size as appropriate in unknown binary file.